# MVC3 DropDownListFor Model is null on PostBack

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, postback, nullreferenceexception, html.dropdownlistfor

I am using a DropDownListFor like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedOrganisationValue, new SelectList(Model.OrganisationList, "Value", "Text"))
```

And I am also using:

```
[Required]
```

As Attribute in the View.

So when I PostBack the View to the Server and the Required Attribute will fail, the View is showed again, but then Model is null. So I will get a NullReferenceException in Model.OrganisationList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the default behaviour. As you know ,MVC does not rely on ViewState, It can not keep the content inside the drop down across Postbacks (generic term). You need to repopulate it again in the ActionMethod.

Comment: Thanks. I expected, that when the RequiredAttribute will fail, that the Controller will not be called. So now I am checking for ModelState.IsValid in ControllerAction on HttpPost and when it is not valid I will return View(new Model()). Thanks!